# How to identify Secure Elements?

Tags: android, secure-element

Is there any way to identify a specific Secure Element?

Use case is that I want to install an applet on a SE and make sure that an applet is installed on the device that initiated the download. In other words how can a TSE prohibit a man in the middle attack.

I already looked through the specifications on the global platform website, but since this is my first time working directly with specifications, I find it hard to find my way around this vast amount of informations.

Answer (score 0):

The APDU "GET DATA" Command specified in the Global Platform Card Specification provides unique identifiers for the given card.